# handle Queues from cake console (cakephp console) on google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cakephp

I want to set up my cakephp app on google app engine but I don't know how can I exec the cake console because I need cronjob for handling queuses

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cakephp-starter-app

Comment: Cakephp run as well but my problem is that I don't know how to run cake console or how set a cronjob who will exec a commande line

Answer (score 1):

solved, a php app on google app engine can be able to run cronjobs through cron.yaml on root path app here is an example of code:

```
cron:
- description: daily summary job
  url: /tasks/summary
  schedule: every 24 hours
  timezone: Australia/NSW
  target: beta
```

then you can upload cron, run: appcfg.py update_cron